# How to print Zweckform 4737 labels?

Tags: printing, label

I am trying to print a load of Zweckform 4737 labels from a web page.  From reading around it sounds like it's more robust to generate a PDF than to use print stylesheets.

There are various libraries out there in various languages for doing this...but unless your specific label is supported, you need to know the exact measurements of the label yourself.  Unfortunately it seems the Zweckform 4737 is not widely supported.  (I will be using a Ruby library at the end of the day, but that's by the by.)

I have looked online but I cannot find the Zweckform 4737's measurements.  I know the basics: 29.6mm x 63.5mm, 3 per row, 27 per sheet.  But I also need (I think) the sheet's left and bottom margins, and the horizontal gap between labels if any.

Does anyone know where I can find this information?  Or should I simply trawl around office stationery shops looking for a pack of the labels and just measure them with a ruler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Aimee Daniells](http://edendevelopment.co.uk/blogs/aimee/) showed me that the [Open Office label wizard](http://twitpic.com/yya9s) has all the information I need.

Thanks Aimee!

Comment: On OS X, printing one or more contacts in the Address Book lets you see all common labels' measurements.